# Getting reasonable performance from a parameterized query in Spring JDBC template

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am trying to execute a very simple query from Spring JDBCTemplate.  I am retrieving one attribute from a record that is identified by primary key.  The entirely of the code is shown below.  When I do this with a query constructed by concatenation (dangerous and ugly, and currently uncommented) it executes in 0.1 second.  When I change my comments and use the parameterized query it executes in 50 seconds.  I would much prefer to get the protection that comes with the parameterized query, however 50 seconds seems like a steep price to pay.  Any hints how this could be made more reasonable.

```
public class JdbcEventDaoImpl {
    private static JdbcTemplate jtemp;
    private static PreparedStatement getJsonStatement;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcEventDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcEventDaoImpl.jtemp = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public String getJdbcForPosting(String aggregationId){
        try {
            return (String)  JdbcEventDaoImpl.jtemp.queryForObject("select PostingJson from PostingCollection where AggregationId = '" + aggregationId + "'", String.class);
            //return (String)  JdbcEventDaoImpl.jtemp.queryForObject("select PostingJson from PostingCollection where AggregationId = ?", aggregationId, String.class);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
            return  "Not Available";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The jdbctemplate shouldn't be static here.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the feedback.  You are right, it that the code would be better if I address our comment.  However this is not the cause of the performance problem.  Both returns work, one of them is acceptably fast, the other is not.  I will look into incorporating your suggestion, but would also be very interested in insight on how to resolve the performance problem.

Comment: So the root cause turns out to be that that database (MSSQLServer) has this field saved in a non-unicode character mapping. When the parameter is shipped separately it is tagged as Unicode and seems to prevent the DB from using the primary key index.  If I change the connection telling it to never send Unicode I get similar performance for both calls.  Unfortunately I can't justify changing this setting for all queries as some may want to send unicode.

Comment: wow. sounds like you need to edit this or create a new question since you have a better idea what the problem is. Does it matter if you use a different jdbc driver (jtds vs microsoft's)?